# how to manage double quotes in the vbscript

Tags: vbscript

```
Set dir = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dir.Add "12", "layout1" 
dir.Add "29", "layout2"
dir.Add "35", "layout3"

For Each slide In presentation.Slides
  xyz = slide.Layout
  msgBox dir.Item(xyz)
next
```

here xyz will give the number and i want to pass the same value to the directory object to get the value of that key. but here the problem is in dir.Item(xyz) if i am not kept double quotes to the xyz then we are not getting the item for the key because it is systax problem, if i keep the double quotes then it will take as xyz only not by the value of xyz. any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

`slide.Layout` returns numbers, so just make the keys of the dictionary numbers as well:

```
Set dir = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dir.Add 12, "layout1" 
dir.Add 29, "layout2"
dir.Add 35, "layout3"

For Each slide In presentation.Slides
  MsgBox dir.Item(slide.Layout)
Next
```

You could also convert the number to a string:

```
Set dir = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dir.Add "12", "layout1" 
dir.Add "29", "layout2"
dir.Add "35", "layout3"

For Each slide In presentation.Slides
  MsgBox dir.Item(CStr(slide.Layout))
Next
```

but that would just increase the complexity of your code without gaining you anything.